# Row level checkbox in R Shiny dataframe

Tags: shiny

Is there a way where we can have a checkbox to an entire data frame instead of a single column?

Something like this:

```
checkboxGroupInput("specy", "Specy", choices = ******entire iris dataframe*****)
```

Instead of:
`checkboxGroupInput("specy", "Specy", choices = levels(iris$Species))`

Comment: What does it mean ? You want to select a cell in the table ?

Comment: Hi Stephane, I want to select an entire row(s) from the table.